# Using Pest.rs, how can I avoid 'peek was called on empty stack' if the PUSH is optional?

Tags: parsing, rust, grammar, peg, pest

Pest.rs has the ability to push and peek onto a stack. This is useful when a delimiter is given by the user like custom-quoting found in Perl, and PostgreSQL (double dollar syntax). How can I do this if the item may not be on the stack. For example, the Exim config file states,

> It is also possible to use newline and other control characters (those with code values less than 32, plus DEL) as separators in lists. **Such separators must be provided literally at the time the list is processed.** For options that are string-expanded, you can write the separator using a normal escape sequence. This will be processed by the expander before the string is interpreted as a list. For example, if a newline-separated list of domains is generated by a lookup, you can process it directly by a line such as this:
>
> ```
> domains = <\n ${lookup mysql{.....}}
> ```

You can see here the token `<\n` which overrides the default separator of `:` is optional. You can see here that the syntax is essentially,

```
list_sep        = ${ "<" ~ (!WHITE_SPACE ~ ANY) }
list            = {
  list_type
  ~ key
  ~ "="
  ~ PUSH(list_sep)?
  ~ !(PEEK ~ ANY)+
  ~ (PEEK ~ !(PEEK ~ ANY))*
}
```

But when I run that I get,

> peek was called on empty stack

Is there anyway to provide for this operation with PEG such that the list is presented to the user as a string, but as an actual list of element tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I've started doing is making sure the `PUSH` always happens. It even seems like an opitional `PUSH` should be a compiler error,

Rather than

```
~ PUSH(list_sep)?
```

Do this,

```
~ PUSH(list_sep?)
```

Comment: I thought of always pushing a normal whitespace first. You have to clear the stack after each rule anyway, I assume.